# How do you create bold axes in flot (jQuery plugin for graphing)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [display x-axis and y-axis lines with out the grid lines using flot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433154/display-x-axis-and-y-axis-lines-with-out-the-grid-lines-using-flot)

How do you make the x- and y-axis appear bold (and possibly with arrows) in flot?  The default behavior is not to show the axes at all.  Thanks.

Comment: Just answered a somewhat similar question, see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433154/display-x-axis-and-y-axis-lines-with-out-the-grid-lines-using-flot

Comment: Perfect.  Could you post the `grid: { markings.... }` part of your answer below so I can accept it as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the flot API, look for [grid markings](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt)...

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, true and to be honest, I should have voted to close it as an exact duplicate since I had answered a very similar question 7 days early (with "essential parts" too)!

Comment: Whoops!  I totally missed your comment earlier.  Thanks for pointing that out.