# Flot: Markings - Size of line stroke

Tags: javascript, flot

Is it possible to change the line stroke of markings? I already know that is possible to change the color of it:

```
markings: [ { yaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#000"},
            { xaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#000" }],
```

I've used this solution to make my axis without the background grid line:
[display-x-axis-and-y-axis-lines-with-out-the-grid-lines-using-flot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433154/display-x-axis-and-y-axis-lines-with-out-the-grid-lines-using-flot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the option:

```
        markings: [ { yaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#000"},
                    { xaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#000" }],
        markingsLineWidth: 2.5, //number
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with the `markingsLineWidth` option that apply to all markings, you can also define `lineWidth` per marking:

```
markings: [ { yaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#000", lineWidth: 5},  // speficic value
            { xaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#000" }],
markingsLineWidth: 2.5, // default value
```

Links to the source code:
Default value: [`markingsLineWidth: 2`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.js#L605)
Per marking value: [`var lineWidth = m.lineWidth || options.grid.markingsLineWidth;`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.js#L2003)