# How to bold multilple y axis line in flot charts?

Tags: jquery, flot

I am working with flot charts. I have multiple y axis. How to make all y axis bold?

```
$(function () {
    function generate(start, end, fn) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; ++i) {
        var x = start + i / 100 * (end - start);
        res.push([x, fn(x)]);
    }
    return res;
}

var data = [
    { data: generate(0, 10, function (x) { return Math.sqrt(x)}), xaxis: 1, yaxis:1 },
    { data: generate(0, 10, function (x) { return Math.sin(x)}), xaxis: 1, yaxis:2 },
    { data: generate(0, 10, function (x) { return Math.cos(x)}), xaxis: 1, yaxis:3 },
    { data: generate(0, 10, function (x) { return Math.tan(x)}), xaxis: 1, yaxis: 4 }
];
var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
                  data,
                  {
                      xaxis: [
                          { position: 'bottom' },
                      ],
                      yaxes: [
                          { position: 'left', labelWidth : 18},
                          { position: 'right', tickColor:'black', labelWidth : 18, tickDecimals: 0},
                          { position: 'right' , tickColor:'black', labelWidth : 18, tickDecimals: 0},
                          { position: 'right', tickColor:'black', labelWidth : 18}
                      ],

                grid: {
                    clickable: true,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    hoverable: true,
                    aboveData: true,
                    markings: [ { yaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: "#000" },
                        { xaxis: { from: 0, to: 0 }, color: 'black' }, { xaxis: { from: 0, to: -1 }, color: "green" }]
                },
                zoom: {
                    interactive: true
                 },
                  });


function getBoundingBoxForAxis(plot, axis) {
    var left = axis.box.left, top = axis.box.top,
        right = left + axis.box.width, bottom = top + axis.box.height;

    // some ticks may stick out, enlarge the box to encompass all ticks
    var cls = axis.direction + axis.n + 'Axis';
    plot.getPlaceholder().find('.' + cls + ' .tickLabel').each(function () {
        var pos = $(this).position();
        left = Math.min(pos.left, left);
        top = Math.min(pos.top, top);
        right = Math.max(Math.round(pos.left) + $(this).outerWidth(), right);
        bottom = Math.max(Math.round(pos.top) + $(this).outerHeight(), bottom);
    });
    return { left: left, top: top, width: right - left, height: bottom - top };
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to make the border around the grid ticker or darker?  Look at the borderWidth property in the grid options: https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid

Comment: not border. looking for axis line make bold.

Comment: Flot, by default, draws a gray grid at certain tick positions surrounded by a square black border.  Which piece of this is the "axis line"?

Comment: if there is multiple axis then axis line separated from grid.

Comment: You need to answer Mark's question.  Perhaps draw us a picture of what you are trying to do/change.

Comment: @Ryley, I think I understand what they are after. Using the above code I threw together a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4Emr9/1/).  user1016195 has colored the xaxis and first yaxis green, but how do you alter yaxis2, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique in the code above uses the "markings" api of flot to overlay a line on the axes.    It appears that this won't work with multiple y axis because the additional axis are off the plot.  What does work though is simply drawing the "bolder" lines directly on the plot's canvas.  For instance to add green y axis lines:

```
ctx = plot.getCanvas().getContext('2d'); //assuming your plot is stored in a variable named plot variable
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.lineWidth = 7;
$.each(plot.getYAxes(), function(){    
    var axesDim = this.box;
    ctx.beginPath();
    xPos = axesDim.left;
    if (this.position == 'left')
    {
        xPos += axesDim.width;
    }
    ctx.moveTo(xPos,axesDim.top);
    ctx.lineTo(xPos,axesDim.top+axesDim.height);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

When executed on the above code, would produce:

[image]

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Emr9/3/).

Comment: thaks..this is what i am looking.

Comment: Is it possible different axis with different colour?

Comment: Sure just change the `ctx.strokeStyle = "green";` line on each loop.

Comment: how to hide bolded axis by clicking the legend?

Comment: That's not so easy.  Since the canvas is static (you can not erase), you'd have to redraw the plot without the bold.  In the API look at the draw() method.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this post about [create bold axes in flot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433154/display-x-axis-and-y-axis-lines-with-out-the-grid-lines-using-flot)

let me know if you need more help

Comment: i need to bold multiple y axis.

Comment: The grid lines and border are drawn on a canvas, you can not adjust it through CSS.